# R: using apply function on a list to get mean of multiple values

Tags: r, apply, mean

I have a list that looks like this. I've split it by 'ID', resulting in about 1,400 different components of the list (each one is a different location containing multiple species observations) .

```
                   ID Species   2013       2008       2003
           AA 1501106      11   1751.047   1504.080   1580.337    
           AA 1501106      11   1856.224   1678.837   1592.824      
           AA 1502114      11   1766.527   1519.468   1647.180
```

So now I know that I can select individual components and summary() will give me the mean, median, etc of each of that specific element for 2013, 2008 and 2003, but with so many components that becomes confusing to sort through

What I would like is to be able to get the mean of every component per year (so the mean for 2013, 2008 and 2003)

using

```
apply(plot_list,mean)
```

doesn't work, presumably because the list is not just one column.

any ideas on how i can solve this?

Comment: The data structure you are showing looks more like data.frame then list. Do you have a list of those data frames? If that is the case, you can write your own function computing means of your structure and then use apply (or lapply if it is on list) with your function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the following:

```
lapply(myList, FUN=function(i) sapply(i[, 3:5], mean))
```

This assumes that your list, which I called myList, is a list of data.frames with the same structure: 5 columns, where the three final columns are those for which you want to calculate the mean.

This will return a list where each element is a vector of length 3.

Comment: This has worked perfectly! it didn't click that i had a list of data.frames. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 2):

We can use `colMeans` after looping through the `list` with `lapply`

```
lapply(myList, function(x) colMeans(x[3:5]))
```

---

However, a better approach might be to apply the function on a single dataset using either `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(myList) %>%
           group_by(ID, Species) %>%
           summarise_each(funs(mean))
```

or `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(myList)[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = .(ID, Species)]
```